# Reset IPMI IP on Supermicro server with videocard died

Tags: ipmi, supermicro

Today I face a server which videoport is dead (no picture when monitor connects to even on reboot), but this server has IPMI.

The problem is, the IP of IPMI is set to some dummy value (I was told that was for security reason), and now I can't change it since no video available.

**Is there any way to reset IPMI IP by changing some jumpers on motherboard or any other non-interactive way?**

Please advice!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Tried to plug an external video card into some PCIe slot?

If there is installed Linux on the server, you also may configure a network settings and user accounts in BMC via IPMI device interface from within the OS using e.g. `ipmiuitl` or `ipmitool` (you will need `ipmi_devintf` module loaded):

Detect a local IPMI BMC:

```
ipmitool mc info
```

See the configuration

```
ipmitool lan print
ipmitool user list <ch>
```

and so on (`<ch>` is a IPMI *channel* for which you do the configuration).

Set the IP address and netmask:

```
ipmitool lan set 2 ipaddr 192.168.1.100
ipmitool lan set 2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

See which subcommands are available:

```
ipmitool lan
ipmitool user
```

There could be some difficulty understanding IPMI channels, what you need to know is that lowest numbered channel usually is Ethernet one, so configure whichever lowest number you'll be allowed. For example, on the HP server ch I've tested these commands it was 2. Don't be too scared, I was first time introduced to the IPMI and to this ipmitool utility on Supermicro server, I managed to do everything I need, this was not hard at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ipmitool` as mentioned in another answer is probably the best option.

Another option, if the server has a serial port then you could connect to that while it is booting.  You should be able to enter the IPMI setup and configure it.  This is an interactive solution though.